# FFMpeg concat demuxer unsafe file name

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

I'm using ffmpeg inside my .net application to merge(concatenate) some short videos with the same encoding and width and height dimensions.
I've created a txt file as the documentation says and this is my txt:

concatTextDirectory is directory of my txt file.

```
file 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a1.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a2.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a3.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a4.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a5.mp4'
```

And this is ffmpeg argument part:

```
ffmpeg.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i " + concatTextDirectory + " -c copy " + videoOut + " -y -report";
```

but it has no result and below is the report

> ffmpeg started on 2016-04-25 at 19:02:30 Report written to
>   "ffmpeg-20160425-190230.log" Command line: ffmpeg.exe -f concat -i
>   "C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\keep.txt" -c copy
>   "C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\keep.mp4" -y -report ffmpeg
>   version N-79546-g13406b6 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg
>   developers   built with gcc 5.3.0 (GCC)   configuration: --enable-gpl 
>   --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmfx --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --enable-zlib   libavutil      55. 22.100 / 55. 22.100   libavcodec     57. 35.100 / 57. 35.100   libavformat    57. 34.102 / 57. 34.102   libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101   libavfilter     6. 44.100 / 
>      6. 44.100   libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100   libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101   libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100 Splitting the commandline. Reading option '-f' ... matched as option
>   'f' (force format) with argument 'concat'. Reading option '-i' ...
>   matched as input file with argument
>   'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\keep.txt'. Reading option '-c' ...
>   matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'copy'. Reading
>   option 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\keep.mp4' ... matched as
>   output file. Reading option '-y' ... matched as option 'y' (overwrite 
>   output files) with argument '1'. Reading option '-report' ... matched 
>   as option 'report' (generate a report) with argument '1'. Finished
>   splitting the commandline. Parsing a group of options: global .
>   Applying option y (overwrite output files) with argument 1. Applying
>   option report (generate a report) with argument 1. Successfully
>   parsed a group of options. Parsing a group of options: input file
>   C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\keep.txt. Applying option f (force
>   format) with argument concat. Successfully parsed a group of options. 
>   Opening an input file: C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\keep.txt.
>   [file @ 00000000027d3ee0] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
>   [concat @ 00000000027d3800] Unsafe file name
>   'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a1.mp4' [AVIOContext @
>   0000000000957ca0] Statistics: 238 bytes read, 0 seeks
>   C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\keep.txt: Operation not permitted

as you can see at the end it says:

> Unsafe file name 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a1.mp4'

... and Operation not permitted.
I've tried adding extra backslashes or change backslashes to forward slashes or escaping double colon, adding double quote or single quote at the beginning or end of concatTextDirectory... none of these changes made any result.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Either run

```
ffmpeg.exe -f concat -safe 0 -i
"C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\keep.txt" -c copy
"C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\keep.mp4
```

Or don't use absolute (full) paths in `keep.txt`

Comment: What isn't safe and why? The example in documentation shows absolute paths, so I think that's not the problem.

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2013-February/138400.html – causes absolute paths to be treated as unsafe. Not sure about the logic of it though!

Comment: I also thought it was suppose to be absolute paths based on docs but apparently that's not right. I made it just filenames and it worked great.

Comment: +1 for using relative path names. All the examples show full.

Comment: +1 `Unsafe file name 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a1.mp4'` so you change `file 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a1.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a2.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a3.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a4.mp4'
file 'C:\Users\mtst\Desktop\Clips\keep\a5.mp4'` to `file 'a1.mp4'
file 'a2.mp4'
file 'a3.mp4'
file 'a4.mp4'
file 'a5.mp4'` and it works